# Prove $\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(a+b\varepsilon^2_k)=a^n+b^n$.

Tags: complex-numbers, contest-math, roots-of-unity

Let $n$ be an odd positive integer and $\varepsilon_0$, $\varepsilon_1$,..., $\varepsilon_{n-1}$ the complex roots of unity of order $n$. Prove that $$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(a+b\varepsilon^2_k)=a^n+b^n,$$ for all complex numbers $a$ and $b$.

I believe this problem comes from the 2000 RMO. I'm not too sure where to really start the problem, any hints?

Comment: Start with $n=3,5$, try figuring out where $\epsilon_k^2$'s are on the unit circle.

Comment: Yep, odds create a bijection so $\varepsilon$'s are simply permutated. But I have a suspicion that this wouldn't wind down into a number theory problem.

Comment: Probably a typo somewhere, on the left we have polynomial of degree n-1 with respect to a and on the right polynomial of degree n.

Comment: Right, $k$ should be $0$. Woops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $b=0,$ the equation holds. Else, let $c=a/b$ and divide by $b^n$ so that we have to show $\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} (c+\epsilon_k^2) = c^n + 1.$ The LHS is simply $\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} (c+\epsilon_k)$ because the $\epsilon_k^2$ form a permutation of the roots of unity as you observed. Now do you see how to finish off with Vieta's Theorem?

Extra hint: What are the roots of $(x-c)^n - 1$?